# Go function with matrix interface as parameter

Tags: function, go, matrix, interface

I don't know how to use an interface as a parameter for a function, I keep getting a syntax error:

```
syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting {
```

But it looks the same as any other function:

```
func getWall(array [][]interface, wallSize float64){
  var currentWall, highWallPrice float64 = 0, 0;
  err := false
  i := 0
  for highWall < wallSize {
    if i >= (len(array)) {
      fmt.Println("Not enough offers for pair " + pair)
      currentWall = wallSize
      err = true
    }else{
      price = getFloat(array[i][0].(string))
      amount = getFloat(array[i][1].(string))
      currentWall = currentWall + price * amount
       i++
    }
  }
  if !fail {
    wallPrice = getFloat(array[i][0].(string))
  }
  return wallPrice, err
}
```

I'm starting to learn golang any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `func getWall(array [][]interface, wallSize float64){` because your parameter need to look like this `[][]interface{}`

Comment: That is correct, thank you very much, can you link any resource that will explain why does it need it?

Comment: I don't think its there any resource about that, but to explain why you need that it's beacuse interface are reserved words so golang compiler needs to know that you expecting interface type instead of declaring one and you always need to make it by that for example when declaring `var someInterface interface{}` you also need to initialize with brackets, thats how I understand that

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar `interface` without `{ ... }` is not a type, just as `struct` without `{ ... }` is not a type, those are just keywords. In both instances `{}` means *empty*, that is: `interface{}` is an empty interface which means an interface with no methods; and `struct{}` is an empty struct which means a struct with no fields... Those are valid types, but the keywords themselves are not types.